# "Unable to create/update fields: Address" - but permissions look fine

Tags: soap-api, leads, fields, .net

I'm attempting to add a Lead using the SOAP API via .NET.

I receive this error:

> Unable to create/update fields: Address. Please check the security settings of this field and verify that it is read/write for your profile or permission set.

However, everywhere I can think to check shows the field is visible and editable.

**Editing field-level security for Address in Lead:**

[image: Field level security for the System Administrator profile]

**Editing field visibility for Address in Lead:**

[image: Field visibility for System Administrator profile]

**Editing field-level security for the System Administrator profile, from the Profiles management tool:**

[image: Field level security for the System Administrator profile in Profile editing tool]

What am I missing?

Comment: How are you trying to send values on the Address field? Remember Address is a compound field (constitutes of different fields) and is Read Only through API. More details on this field -- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_lead.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Address isn't a "real" field, it's a "compound field" (a set of fields that can be queried as one). Instead, you need to set Street, City, State (or StateCode), PostalCode, and Country (or CountryCode). Compound fields can be used to query all of the base components, but cannot be used to update data in the database.

Comment: Agreed. The "possible duplicate" question is for the Account object. This answer is what you need for the Lead object.